# Returning count of 0 if value doesn't exist Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set 2 variables as counts of a specific value in a column.

I have one variable here:

```
missing_gmt = missing_records._merge.value_counts().Missing_in_GMTLib
```

That correctly returns: `44`

I also have another variable here:

```
missing_nsl = missing_records._merge.value_counts().Missing_in_NSL
```

Which should return `0` (no records exist) but instead is throwing:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Missing_in_NSL'
```

How can I bypass this error so it returns `0` instead?

Comment: How about `try`...`except`?

Comment: It'd help if you provided a [mre], i.e. an example version of `missing_records._merge`, or, maybe even simpler, `missing_records._merge.value_counts()`

Comment: @BigBen Yep, that would work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Series` support `.get()`, so:

```
.value_counts().get('Missing_in_NSL', 0)
```

Docs: [`Series.get()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) (though the examples there are for `df.get()`)